# Why does Oracle Database rounds numbers smaller than `1e-130`

Tags: oracle

Is this behaviour documented somewhere and can full double precision be enabled?

repro queries:

```
select 1e-130; /* 0.0...1 result */
select 1e-131; /* 0 result */
```

online repro: https://dbfiddle.uk/5uwlkJaB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NUMBER Data Type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-75209AF6-476D-4C44-A5DC-5FA70D701B78)

> The NUMBER data type stores zero as well as positive and negative
> fixed numbers with absolute values from 1.0 x 10^-130 to but not
> including 1.0 x 10^126.

[BINARY_DOUBLE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/23/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-12FE5221-9B49-4110-8D16-BF51BCED5562)

> ```
> Value BINARY_FLOAT    BINARY_DOUBLE 
>         Maximum positive finite value
>         3.40282E+38F  1.79769313486231E+308
>
>         Minimum positive finite value
>         1.17549E-38F 2.22507485850720E-308
> ```

```
SQL> select 1e-130 from dual;

    1E-130
----------
1.000E-130

SQL> select 1e-131 from dual;

    1E-131
----------
         0

SQL> select 1e-131d from dual;

   1E-131D
----------
  1.0E-131

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for mentioning the `BINARY_DOUBLE` type.